# Create link from filesite matter folder to launch URL

Tags: c#, com, sdk, autonomy, imanage

I'm basically trying to create a link from a worksite folder in FileSite to take the user to our (Web based) CRM system or Case management system as shown below.
When the user right clicks the matter the option button (Goto CRM) will be available for then to click, I have created this in the following regkey

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Interwoven\Worksite\8.0\FileSite\Commands\Workspace] “Commands”.
```

Once the button Goto CRM is clicked, the matter numbers (all fields if possible) are used to compile the URL for the CRM webpage. e.g. `http://Casemangesyatem/test9999.1.apx`

I don’t know how this is achieved or what the file compiled is or how to create it, any examples notes would be greatly appreciated.

- So how or what is used to compile the file that is location/called by the regkey
- What do I use to create this file and how do I do it

Thanks you.

*This is the only site that I have found with any reference to work-site sdk. I'm new to work-site sdk and would appreciate any kind of help with example code.*

Answer (score 0):

To run some custom code when a user selects your new right click option, you'll need to create a new DLL in Visual Studio to do the actions you need (e.g. redirecting the user to a custom website).

The worksite SDK contains some sample ICommands in VB.NET and C# to get you started. The main requirement for your custom code is that it implement the `IManExtLib.ICommand` interface like below:

```
Namespace MyCustomApp
Public Class IManageToInteraction
    Implements IMANEXTLib.ICommand
...
```

In the registry key below the Commands value should contain the comma separated list of the ClassIDs of the ICommands you want to appear in the right click menus at that level.

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Interwoven\Worksite\8.0\FileSite\Commands\Workspace]
```

For example the following value includes some of the standard entries and our custom class from above and would appear in the right click menu of a workspace within Filesite.

```
IManExt2.AddShortcutsCmd,IManExt.SearchCmd,MyCustomApp.IManageToInteraction
```

Comment: Hi G David,
I appreciate you responding to my cry for help as I don’t have access to the worksite SDK, I have been trying to search the web for some help you have been the first to respond again thanks you.
I have found a couple of documents like MHDLL32 and   the extension library which are very good if I know what I was supposed to do with them, I'm not a developer but I'm learning (very slowly lol).
Can I be cheeky to ask if you have any samples or steps that I can follow to achieve this as my first project, I would be very gratefully if you can get me started.
Many thanks
R